# Youtube DL ["entries"] list is empty when using .exctract_info on a playlist

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-dl

It works with singular musics, but not with playlists.

`print(playlist)` is printing the following:

```
{'_type': 'playlist', 'entries': [], 'id': 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLSW0wsKdfobdWzuTOinJal0Ve7klJfHk8 ', 'extractor': 'youtube:search', 'webpage_url': 'ytsearch:https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLSW0wsKdfobdWzuTOinJal0Ve7klJfHk8 ', 'webpage_url_basename': 'playlist', 'extractor_key': 'YoutubeSearch'}
```

```
async def search_yt(item):

    with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    
    playlist = ydl.extract_info("ytsearch:{}".format(item), download=False)
    print(playlist)

    for i in playlist["entries"]:
        source.append(await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(i['formats'][0]['url'], **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
        info_playlist.append(i["title"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the spaces at the end of the options.

Instead of:

```
'id': 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLSW0wsKdfobdWzuTOinJal0Ve7klJfHk8 '
```

Use:

```
'id': 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLSW0wsKdfobdWzuTOinJal0Ve7klJfHk8'
```

See [Google Colab working sample](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1bk9od2yoTYh5gjDVqY0PMcetWq9LAsXh?usp=sharing)